# 'wget' is not recognized in Jupyter Notebook, but runs in Command Line

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I recently installed *wget*, both from https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/ and also using

```
pip install wget
```

I put the *wget.exe* file in C:\Windows\System32, and when I type

```
wget -h
```

into the command line, it runs perfectly fine, and returns the help list for *wget*. However, when I run *wget* from jupyter notebooks using the code below,

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-introduction-to-machine-learning/main/Data/ml-basics/grades.csv
df_students = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-introduction-to-machine-learning/main/Data/ml-basics/grades.csv',delimiter=',',header='infer')
df_students.head()
```

I get: 'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have done quite some research now and none of the solutions seem to be working for me. I have a slight suspicion it might have to do with my system PATH variables but I can't seem to understand why Jupyter Notebooks cannot find wget.

Comment: `wget` module you installed with `pip` is not used like that. See [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/wget/). And the command `wget` is most likely not in `PATH`, as you suspect. An easy fix is to copy it somewhere that is in `PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

Use curl instead:

```
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-introduction-to-machine-learning/main/Data/ml-basics/grades.csv
df_students = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-introduction-to-machine-learning/main/Data/ml-basics/grades.csv',delimiter=',',header='infer')
df_students.head()
```

The Output:

```
Name,StudyHours,Grade
Dan,10,50
Joann,11.5,50
Pedro,9,47
Rosie,16,9
.....
```